# How to correctly cast list in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics, arraylist, collections

I have a list for example of type `People`. My list can contain only elements of type `Student` or only elements of type `Worker`:

```
 interface People {
        val name: String
        val age: Int
    }

    data class Student(
        override val name: String,
        override val age: Int,
        val course: Int
    ) : People

    data class Worker(
        override val name: String,
        override val age: Int,
        val position: String
    ) : People
```

At some point I need to know the exact type of the list (student or worker).
Can I safely find out the exact type? So far I've written this code, but it doesn't look very good:

```
fun someLogic(items: List<People>): List<People> {
    return (items as? List<Student>) ?: (items as? List<Worker>)
?.filter {}
....
}
```

Also, I get a warning:

> Unchecked cast

Can you please tell me how to perform such transformations correctly?

Comment: This feels like a badly designed list to begin with. Why is the list not generic, possibly even reified if needed? `List<T>` with `T : People`. Why is there a single code flow that attempts to satisfy both cases, while not being happy with just `People`?

Comment: What do you want actually want the `someLogic` to do? Because you can get rid of `Unchecked cast` but at the end of that expression it will always be `People` as a common denominator of the two.

Comment: What you have there is a list where _each item_ can be either a Worker or a Student, but there's nothing _relating_ the types of different items in the list. If you want a list where all the items must be of the same type, then you need a generic list, as Zabuzard says — and then the type system will know what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At runtime, the type parameter you used to create the list is not available. e.g. it is impossible to distinguish between the following two situations:

```
val students: List<People> = listOf<Student>(student1, student2)
val people: List<People> = listOf<People>(student1, student2)
```

This is because of [type erasure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#type-erasure).

The only information you have at runtime that can help determine a list's element type is the type of its elements.

So if a list has no elements, there is no way of knowing what type of list it is. Though in most situations, you don't need to anyway.

So assuming the list can only be a list of all students, or a list of all workers, but not a list containing a mixture of students and workers, you can determine the type of the list by checking the first element.

```
when (items.firstOrNull()) {
    null -> { /* cannot determine the type */ }
    is Student -> { /* is a list of students */ }
    is Worker -> { /* is a list of worker */ }

    // you can remove this branch by making the interface sealed
    else -> { /* someone made another class implementing People! */  }
}
```

If you want to get a `List<Student>` or `List<Worker>` *out* of this on the other hand, you can just use `filterIsInstance`:

```
val students = items.filterIsInstance<Student>()
val worker = items.filterIsInstance<Worker>()
```

whichever list is not empty, then the type of `items` is the type of that list.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check that `List<People>` is `List<Student>` you can use this extension function:

```
fun List<People>.isStudentList(): Boolean {
    // returns true if no element is not Student, so all elements are Student
    return all { it is Student } 
}
```

And if you want to cast `List<People>` to `List<Student>`, you can use map, and this cast is safe so let's say that there is some `People` that the are not `Student` so the cast is going to return null instead of `Student` because of `as?` and the `mapNotNull` is going to exclude null elements so in worst cases where you pass a list that doesn't contain any `Student` this function is going to return an empty list:

```
fun List<People>.toStudentList(): List<Student> {
    // This is going to loop through the list and cast each People to Student
    return mapNotNull { it as? Student }
}
```

Or you can just use `filterIsInstance<Student>` this will work the same as `toStudentList` above:

```
list.filterIsInstance<Student>()
```

And the same approach can be used for `Worker`

Comment: Why the double negation? Just use `all { it is Student }`...

Comment: @Jorn Yes that's better, I totally forgot about `all`

Comment: also there is no need for the second function it's just `filterIsInstance<Student>()`

Comment: @TheLibrarian I didn't know about `filterIsInstance`, thanks for help. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve the problem with more specific classes.

You can define:

```
interface PeopleList<P : People> : List<P>

class StudentList : PeopleList<Student> {
   // add implementation
}

class WorkerList : PeopleList<Worker> {
   // add implementation
}
```

You can then easily check the types of these lists. Each of those classes can then provide guarantees that you are not mixing `Student` and `Worker` objects in the same `List`, something you can't do with plain `List<People>` objects.

Note also you are better off writing your code avoiding checking types if at all possible. Much better to add methods to the `PeopleList` interface and force the subclasses to implement them, for example:

```
interface PeopleList<P : People> : List<P> {
    fun doSomethingGood()
}
```

Then you can call these methods at the appropriate time, instead of checking the type. This approach keeps the functionality associated with the subtypes alongside those subtypes and not scattered through the code at the various points where you have to check the type of `PeopleList`.